# Gitlab Pipeline using Azure image how to access variables?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, azure-cli

I have a very simple CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab that looks like this:

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

variables:
  APP: "MyApp"

stages:
  - build

test_build:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  script:
    - echo $APP
    - $name='prefix' + $APP + 'suffix'
    - echo $name
```

When I run this pipeline, the first script line, `echo $APP`, correctly prints `"MyApp"`. However the second line fails with the following:

```
/bin/bash: Line 121: 'prefix': command not found.
```

My question is, how can I use pipeline variables inline azure cli commands?

Comment: Replace the line starting with  `$name=` with `name="prefix $APP suffix"`

Comment: Oh, finally, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of Bash syntax: Replace the line starting with `$name=` to `name="prefix $APP suffix"`